# Apache mod_rewrite and PHP ?argument=something

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get all HTML and PHP files on my site to redirect through the index.php, so that they can have common frames applied to them, a templating solution I coded that I found to be quite elegant. Anywho, I'm having issues with my PHP files, specifically those that have arguments after them.

My regular rule for PHP files is the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ index.php?page=$1&type=1 [NC,L]
```

This works fine for any pages that have no arguments, but you can see that any PHP documents that have

```
?argument=something
```

end up as:

```
index.php?page=path/to/page?argument=something&type=1
```

which is not a working solution at all. Now, what's bothering me here is the $ at the end of the rule, shouldn't that cause it to fail if there is anything after the .php?

Anywho, I tried rewriting the rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+).php\?(.+)$ index.php?page=$1&type=1&$2 [NC,L]
```

but that simply doesn't trigger at all. It seems that the regex flavor used in mod_rewrite is far different than I'm used to working with, so I'm sure these are simple mistakes I've made, but I can't seem to find decent documentation for *this* flavor of regex other than the most basic of examples.

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try qsa in your rule, which stands for "query string append" - mod_rewrite will then append any query string from the original URL to the rewritten URL

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ index.php?page=$1&type=1 [NC,L,qsa]
```

RewriteRule doesn't match against the query string, which is why your second attempt did not work. Here's the relevant note from [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

> The Pattern will not be matched
>   against the query string. Instead, you
>   must use a RewriteCond with the
>   %{QUERY_STRING} variable. You can,
>   however, create URLs in the
>   substitution string, containing a
>   query string part. Simply use a
>   question mark inside the substitution
>   string, to indicate that the following
>   text should be re-injected into the
>   query string. When you want to erase
>   an existing query string, end the
>   substitution string with just a
>   question mark. To combine a new query
>   string with an old one, use the [QSA]
>   flag.

Comment: Yay! That worked like a charm. I didn't know it wasn't testing the whole string. ^_^